# Flink timeWindow get start time

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm calculating a count (summing 1) over a timewindow as follows:

```
mappedUserTrackingEvent
            .keyBy("videoId", "userId")
            .timeWindow(Time.seconds(30))
            .sum("count")
```

I would like to actually add the window start time as a key field too. so the result would be something like:

```
key: videoId=123,userId=234,time=2016-09-16T17:01:30
value: 50
```

So essentially aggregate count by window. End Goal is to draw a histogram of these windows.

How can I add the start of window as a field in the key? and following that align the window to 00s or 30s in this case? Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `apply()` method of the `WindowFunction` provides a `Window` object, which is a `TimeWindow` if you use `keyBy().timeWindow()`. The `TimeWindow` object has two methods, `getStart()` and `getEnd()` which return the timestamp of the window's start and end, respectively.

At the moment it is not possible use the `sum()` aggregation together with a `WindowFunction`. You need to do something like:

```
 mappedUserTrackingEvent
        .keyBy("videoId", "userId")
        .timeWindow(Time.seconds(30))
        .apply(new MySumReduceFunction(), new MyWindowFunction());`
```

`MySumReduceFunction` implements the `ReduceFunction` interface and compute the sum by incrementally aggregating the elements that arrive in the window. The `MyWindowFunction` implements `WindowFunction`. It receives the aggregated value through the `Iterable` parameter and enriches the value with the timestamp obtained from the `TimeWindow` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method `aggregate` instead of sum.
In  `aggregate` set the secondly parameter implements `WindowFunction` or extends `ProcessWindowFunction`.
I am using the Flink-1.4.0 , recommend to use `ProcessWindowFunction`, like:

```
mappedUserTrackingEvent
    .keyBy("videoId", "userId")
    .timeWindow(Time.seconds(30))
    .aggregate(new Count(), new MyProcessWindowFunction();

public static class MyProcessWindowFunction extends ProcessWindowFunction<Integer, Tuple2<Long,  Integer>, Tuple, TimeWindow>
{
    @Override
    public void process(Tuple tuple, Context context, Iterable<Integer> iterable, Collector<Tuple2<Long,  Integer>> collector) throws Exception
    {
        context.currentProcessingTime();
        context.window().getStart();
    }
}
```